# How to use ORDER by Rand() while doing Union

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to union the results from two select statements and each of the results should return in random order using ORDER BY RAND(), I tried something similar to:

```
query = "
Select user.id FROM user WHERE user.age > 18 ORDER BY RAND()

UNION 

SELECT user.id FROM user WHERE user.age < 13 ORDER BY RAND()

"
```

The ideal output is(given each selects only return 3 rows):

example1:   21, 31, 50   12, 11, 10

example2:   31, 50, 21   10, 12, 11

The result from the first select always appear before the second select result and each result set in random order.

I could have just separate each query and then merge the result, but I wonder whether it's possible to accomplish this in one query

Answer (score 4):

Don't use `union`.  Just use two keys for `order by`:

```
Select u.id
FROM user u
WHERE u.age > 18 or u.age < 13
ORDER BY (u.age > 18) DESC, RAND();
```

Comment: Wouldn't this also select ages 14-17 ?

Comment: @HerbertVan-Vliet . . . Good catch.  I head read the "13" as an "18", so no filtering was necessary.

Comment: Nifty solution now :)

Answer (score 2):

The MySQL UNION documentation[0] indicates you can apply an `ORDER BY` clause to the entire result set:

```
query = "
(Select user.id FROM user WHERE user.age > 18)

UNION 

(SELECT user.id FROM user WHERE user.age < 13)

ORDER BY RAND()

"
```

The key is to wrap each `SELECT` in parenthesis so the `ORDER BY` gets applied to the whole set and not just the second query.

[0] https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/union.html

Comment: will this give me always the users whose ages are greater than 18 then give  me the users whose are less than 13, like 19, 23, 34(result from first select ) followed by 12, 4, 5 (result from second)

Answer (score 2):

If you need to combine ORDER BY RAND() with a UNION anyway, you can do the following:

```
SELECT * FROM (SELECT user.id FROM user WHERE user.age > 18 ORDER BY RAND()) a
UNION 
SELECT * FROM (SELECT user.id FROM user WHERE user.age < 13 ORDER BY RAND()) b
```

For the TS' case, this needs to be adapted, because for mySQL:

> However, use of ORDER BY for individual SELECT statements implies
>   nothing about the order in which the rows appear in the final result
>   because UNION by default produces an unordered set of rows.

T-SQL says the sets are concatenated.

Answer (score 1):

I found out I can use pseudo-column to accomplish this

```
query = "
SELECT DISTINCT id
from(
Select user.id, 1 as role  FROM user WHERE user.age > 18 

UNION 

SELECT user.id, 2 as role  FROM user WHERE user.age < 13 
)a
order by role ASC, RAND()
"
```

Comment: The DISTINCT is in this case not necessary because the ages do not overlap.

Answer (score 0):

ORDER BY  NEWID()

This will create a temp table with random ID's and will display the same.

Answer (score 0):

No need to use UNION because both queries use same table.

SELECT user.id FROM user WHERE user.age < 13 OR user.age > 18 ORDER BY RAND()